# Structure React events on global config

Tags: reactjs

We are working on a new React application but I am a bit struggling on how to handle all these events. One of the requirements I have is that I need to be able to *realtime* update the application configuration.

I read this article which pushed me to some directions but I am still now 100% convinced: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

**For example:**

I have a `LoginForm` component which, as it says, handles the login form. There are 2 configurable settings on this form:

- Where is the endpoint for the webservice
- Where should i redirect to once the login is ok

The question now is how should I structure that with the configuration. The configuration itself will be a JSON file hosted somewhere on the local filesystem and will be read every 5 minutes for example to check for changes. I can of course create a global eventemitter but is this really the way forward?

Other way around, do i need to keep passing all these small events down the pipe?

Hope that somebody can help me with some insights and maybe some good examples where it is handled in a proper way

Thanks alot

Comment: You can put this in top-level component's state (or a store if you have one) and pass the config to children via props or context. Then run an interval to check for configuration changes. When there is change, just update the state and all children components will get the newly updated configs.

Comment: You really should consider using Redux. What you are describing is exactly the kind of problem it was meant to solve.

Comment: As @Smaft said... Redux 100%.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info on Redux, already been looking at this though but is there anyone with some good integration examples or reads? @Smaft

Concerning the push from a top level component towards children on props, its not really working when the app gets too big i believe